# Post XML request with PEM Key

Tags: xml, post, xml-serialization, rsa, pem

I am using Burpsuite to test SSH-public key credentials via an XML POST Request.  Essentially I need to send the PEM file text as part of an XML element, like this:

```
<PEMKey>-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIICXAIBAAK etc...-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</PEMKey>
```

How do I properly format the contents of the PEM file as a string to be submitted as raw XML?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve the white-space, you could use

```
<PEMKey xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</PEMKey>
```

or encode the whole text in base-64 again.